# Retrieve date time and reformat it

Tags: javascript, datetime, format, momentjs

I am trying to capture a future date stamp in Postman using json.  I am able to retrieve the entire datetime. My code looks like this:

```
var moment = require('moment')
pm.collectionVariables.set("current_timestamp", moment().toISOString())
pm.collectionVariables.set("future_timestamp", moment().add(1, 'day').toISOString())
```

I am pulling back in the following information:

```
current_timestamp=2021-03-31T16:11:08.169Z
future_timestamp=2021-04-01T16:11:08.169Z
```

The Web Service I am building for does not need the milliseconds.  The format needs to be ***"YYYY-M-DDTHH:M:SSZ"***.  When I try to wrap the last function in a format request:

```
pm.collectionVariables.set("future_timestamp", moment().add(1, 'day').toISOString().format("YYYY-MM-DD") // as an example
```

I get the following error from postman:

> TypeError: moment(...).add(...).toISOString(...).format is not a function

I am pretty new to JSON (I've used VB for a very long time)  How do I format my response to meet my web service's requirement of ***"YYYY-M-DDTHH:M:SSZ"***.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the [tour] and read [ask] and other articles in the [help]. I've taken the liberty of adding the [javascript] tag, as it appears you are using that language, and language tags are important in getting the right eyes on your question. Please do [edit] your question for anything I might have missed.

Answer (score 1):

Once you do `.toISOString()` on the moment object, it becomes a string and calling `.format()` on that string gives you this error since it is no longer a moment object.

If you want a string in the specified format, you can omit `.toISOString()` and use format.

So

```
pm.collectionVariables.set("future_timestamp", moment().add(1, 'day').format("YYYY-MM-DD") // as an example
```

Keep in mind that using `.format()` will retain your timezone and this output won't be in UTC